# Why there is no quantum effects in carbon nano tubes while these effects are seen in silicon chips?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

I just want to know why we cant we just go beyond 5 nano meter in silicon chips ,
while we can go 1 nano meter in carbon nanotubes.

If we go beyond 5 nano meter in silicon transistors we may encounter quantum effects like tunneling ,etc.?

Why this is not happening in carbon nano tubes and stating it as future replacement of silicon transistors ?